# Resources folder in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2012

I write you all for a problem with my c# library. It needs an XML file that uses as a dictionary. Since the files will not change I would like the dll already contained the file and requires no memory references to it.

```
System.Xml.XmlTextReader reader = new System.Xml.XmlTextReader(@G:\Project\dictionary.xml");
```

So I put the XML file in the "Resources" folder of visual studio, but now I do not know how to get that file. If you always use the memory reference to use the library without also enter the file, it does not work. How can I do? If I open the dll with a notepad I see that the XML file is in.

Answer (score 2):

This should give you an idea:

[image]

1. add a *.resx file
2. drag and drop you XML File onto it.
3. Use it!